# Linux's context switching speedy?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, context-switching

I'm studying linux kernel.
I read this, "Linux's system call is faster than many other OS, reason is 
linux's fast context switching time. Process's context switching is very 
simple and system call handler is simple too".

What's mean of this?? why linux'x context switching is faster than other OS?
Why can speak linux's system call handler is simple?

Comment: Well i'm not sure about performance.. but the structure that represents the process control block in the kernel scheduler is certainly not what I would call "simple". The "task_struct" structure definition alone is 580 lines of code: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h#L501